# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. C#

Tags: c#

```
class Server
{
    public int port = 7777;
    private Boolean IsServerRunning = true;
    public List<Socket> Clients;
    public int MessageSize = 4096;
    public string StrIpServ = "127.0.0.1";
    public int backlog = 15;
    private IPAddress IpServ;
    public void StartServer()
    {
        IpServ = IPAddress.Parse(StrIpServ);
        Thread serv = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoServer));
        serv.Start();
    }
    public void DoServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("listener thread started");
        IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IpServ, port);
        Socket ConnectReceiver = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        ConnectReceiver.Bind(LocalEndPoint);
        ConnectReceiver.Listen(backlog);
        while (IsServerRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket Cli = ConnectReceiver.Accept();
                if (Cli.Connected) 
                { 
                    Clients.Add(Cli);
                }
                byte[] bytes = new byte[MessageSize];
                ConnectReceiver.Receive(bytes);
                MsgSender(bytes);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }        
    }
```

в строчке Clients.Add(Cli); и происходит эта ошибка. Я программирую недавно поэтому не могу понять в чем проблема, заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, вы забыли написать, например, в конструкторе класса

```
Clients = new List<Socket>();
```

Или даже в определении класса

```
List<Socket> Clients = new List<Socket>();
```